# Page Heading Error

Tags: header-footer

I get the 'List of tables' title as a right page heading. How do I fix that?

```
    \documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {{%                                    %%% original \MakeUppercase
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{typearea} 

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%per allineamento a sx delle colonne
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\chapter{Lorem}
\section{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.


\chapter{Ipsum}
\section{dolor sit amet lorem ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some comments: don't use `pslatex` which is largely obsolete, and you load `mathdesign` afterwards; `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` should be removed; the two `\addcontentsline` commands are wrong.

Comment: @egreg: what is wrong with \addcontentsline? What should I have instead?

Comment: The `\addcontentsline` for the bibliography must go near the bibliography. But it's better to use the `tocbibind` package rather than adding it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that should do what you need. I've removed many packages; add them at will, but take into consideration some facts:

- `pslatex` is obsolete and you also load `mathdesign`
- `amssymb` is not to be loaded along `mathdesign`
- the IPA fonts are either compatible with Computer Modern or Times and they don't mix at all with Charter

Here is a skeleton document.

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

%\usepackage{emptypage} % uncomment for getting really empty pages

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%%% Add your packages

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to produce mock text

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}
A Frontispiece?


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Lorem}
\section{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\kant

\chapter{Ipsum}
\section{dolor sit amet lorem ipsum}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I download fixltx2e? I cannot find the .zip file online.

Comment: Also, why would you suggest I add fancyhdr?

Comment: The call for `fixltx2e` was in *your* example. Since `fancyhdr` does the job easily, why not using it?

Comment: Yes, now I realize that, sorry. I'll use fancyhdr as you said.