# fancyhdr package: changing header from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, capitalization

I need to change my headers from uppercase to lowercase using `fancyhdr`. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[lo]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[ro,le]{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{{My Header Title}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
\chaptername}\ \thechapter.%
\ #1}{}}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind} 

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%per allineamento a sx delle colonne

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\hyphenation{Boont-ling}


\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

Something here.

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter  

\chapter{Lorem}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.



\chapter{Ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.



\chapter{dolor}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.



\end{document}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of fancyhdr, section 9 "the scoops of LaTeX marks".

Comment: I'm asking why you don't look at the code I provided you in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83589/4427), where `\nouppercase` is used (with which, of course, headers come out *not* all uppercase).

Comment: @egreg I did but still all uppercase!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did, I added the code provided there, still doesn't work.

Comment: @Costi: Then you did something wrong. But as long as you don't show what you are actually doing nobody will be able to correct your code.

Comment: @Costi Remove the redefinition of `\chaptermark` that in my code wasn't present; of course it's that redefinition that causes the problem. Also the settings `\fancyhead{}` and `\fancyhead[C]{My Header Title}` should be removed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code has some wrong parts.

### First

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[lo]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[ro,le]{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{{My Header Title}}
```

The last two lines cancel out the settings made before, so they should be removed.

### Second

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
\chaptername}\ \thechapter.%
\ #1}{}}
```

This code is useless and should be removed.

### Third

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

This line reverts to the standard headings of the `book` class, which use uppercase. Remove it.

Comment: It does work, but now there's another problem. The page number exceeds the margins.

Comment: Put the call to `geometry` before `fancyhdr` and remove the call to `typearea`

Comment: That does the trick!!

Answer (score -1):

`\lowercase{}` can do that.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\lowercase{My Header Title}}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't do it. Maybe there's a conflict with other packages.

Comment: `\lowercase` will not work with header generated with e.g. `\leftmark`. You need `\nouppercase` from the fancyhdr package.

Comment: What should I do with this:\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[lo]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[ro,le]{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\lowercase{My Header Title}}